# Authenticate GitHub API on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, api, axios, github-api

I'm building a simple application on react using axios and the GitHub API, but i'm having problems with the API authentication.

I've manage to get some requests, but I need to authenticate my access since I have a limited number of requests avaliable: "API rate limit exceeded for **.**.**.**. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit.)"

I've generated a token for a GitHub account but I don't know how to use it. Here is what I tried:

```
    const fetchUsers = () => {
        axios.get('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + props.user, {
            'auth': {
              'username': my_user,
              'token': my_token,
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            const users = response.data.items;
            const updatedUsers = users.map(users => {
                return {
                    ...users,
                }
            })
            setUsersLoaded(true)
            setUsers(updatedUsers)
        })
    }
```

Can I validate it with axios or do I have to work with a different approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) you have to add an authorization header.

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + props.user, {
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': `token ${my_token}` 
  }
})
```

Otherwise github themselves actually offer a library called [octokit](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js) which you can use instead of axios.

Comment: Great! I'm going to work with their library it looks perfect for what I need. Thanks.

Comment: given the token has only read permissions, is it acceptable to just paste the token in my file in a public git repo?  
like: `'Authorization': "token ABCDEF1235"`
What's the recommended way for this when the token has write permissions and is client-side JS? Or you technically can't so that's where server-side JS comes in play so the token is never sent to the client?

Comment: scratch my previous comment, just realized it's not just read only